# Какие причины могут быть у ошибки MySQL "command denied to user"?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table
```

Занималась передачей данных форме, до этого на других формах использовалась база нормально (пользователь - root), ну вот теперь вот такая ошибка вылазит и база не используется нормально

Запрос:

```
$sql='select a.id, b.city_lng, b.city_lat from homeplus.t_city as a, homeplus.t_city_coord as b where a.id=b.city_id and a.city_name_rus="'.$city_name.'"'; $res=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

Файл connectDB.php

```
function OpenDB(){
   //$vDB=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","iq2k47","homeplus_test1");
    $vDB=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","homeplus");
    if(!$vDB){
        die("Connect error (".mysqli_connect_errno().") ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($vDB, "utf8");
    return $vDB;
}
```

Comment: покажи запрос...

Comment: Проблемы с запросом. Из-за него полетело все, что работало раньше и не касалось этой страницы. Вернула все обратно, запрос удалила, сделала немного по-другому - работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лекции о том, что root можно использовать только в денвере на домашнем компе вам, наверно, уже читали ни раз.

Заходите в phpmyadmin, пользователи, привелегии. Смотрите какие у юзера root. Скорее всего, сняты галки, напротив команды select (или и еще каких).

Ошибка дословно означает, что данному пользователю (root) данную команду (select) для данной таблицы (уж не information schema ли? =)) использовать нельзя: отсутствуют права.

Comment: @knes, пользуюсь только на домашнем компе.
Зашла, там аж три root, но у всех стоят на всем галочки

Comment: еще хочу заметить, что ошибка воде должна быть так: SELECT command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table, но у меня отсутствует имя пользователя, хотя коннектилась к базе как root.

Comment: Зачем вам столько? =) "лишних" поудаляйте. Оставьте только самого первого, у которого ID наименьший. Это в любом случае, чтобы система не блудилась.

Comment: Он иногда бывает, рута не пишет. Это глючок денвера. =)
СТОП. а к этому файлу подключен файл коненекта к бд или сразу идет запрос?

Comment: Нужен файл коннекта(Можно с замазанным паролем), кусок(+3 строки), где файл подключается, кусок где идет запрос(+3 строки), ошибки PHP.
в начале файла добавить:
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: Доковырялась в пользователях, теперь отказ в phpmyadmin. Зайти не могу....((

Comment: Денвер? Тогда просто его переставьте. Он все информацию хранит в файликах.
Базы можете забэкапить, сайты он тронуть не должен

Comment: файл connectDB.php
function OpenDB(){
   //$vDB=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","iq2k47","homeplus_test1");
    $vDB=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","homeplus");
 if(!$vDB){
  die("Connect error (".mysqli_connect_errno().") ".mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 mysqli_set_charset($vDB, "utf8");
 return $vDB;
}

Запрос:
$sql='select a.id, b.city_lng, b.city_lat from homeplus.t_city as a,
       homeplus.t_city_coord as b where a.id=b.city_id and a.city_name_rus="'.$city_name.'"';
  $res=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());